# Read remote file on another server with php

Tags: php

I want to run my script on my server (linux), and read files from a folder on another remote server (windows).
Its work fine locally on my local machine but not connecting to another server.
I tried to use fopen() this way:

```
 $filename = 'exampleFile.txt';
   $file = fopen ('smb://172.16.38.x/folderShare/folderFiles' . '\\' . $filename , "r");

    if (!$file) {
        echo "Unable to open remote file to write.\n";
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "Reading file\n";
    }
```

I get the error: Unable to open remote file to write.
How can I connect to another server with php.

Comment: PHP cannot usually get files from an SMB share using just `fopen()`. Have you looked at any tools like https://github.com/icewind1991/SMB

Comment: PHP has a limited number of [protocol wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) that it supports, and SMB/CIFS/etc are not included. You'll either need to actually mount the share to the machine, or use a 3rd-party library like @TheGentleman has suggested.

Comment: @TheGentleman the script run on centos and i want to read a file in a shared folder of Windows